# Python Dataframe: For Each Row Pick One Value from Five Different Columns And Place In New Column Based on if Value is in List

Tags: python, dataframe, list, filter, isin

Let's say I'm starting with the following input table below:

| date | id | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val_final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-29 | B3241 | 496C |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2023-09-08 | A3290 | 349C | 078F | 274F |  |  |  |
| 2023-09-12 | D2903 | 349C | 072F | 307C | 170F | 201D |  |
| 2023-09-14 | I13490 | 497C | 0349 | 303F | 101A |  |  |

The code to create the initial input table is below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':["2023-08-29","2023-09-08","2023-09-12", "2023-09-14"],'id':["B3241","A3290","D2903", "I13490"],'val1':["496C","349C","349C", "497C"], 'val2':["","078F","072F", "0349"], 'val3':["","274F","307C", "303F"], 'val4':["","","170F", "101A"], 'val5':["","","201D",""]})
```

I want to look at columns "val1" through "val5" and see which rows contain a value from my code list.  I want to populate the "val_final" column accordingly (if the value is in the list).

```
code_list = ['349C', '303F', '201D', '497C']
```

If multiple columns contain values from code_list I want to pick the one that's on the right most column.

Given the above logic, my desired output table would look like this:

| date | id | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val_final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-08-29 | B3241 | 496C |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2023-09-08 | A3290 | 349C | 078F | 274F |  |  | 349C |
| 2023-09-12 | D2903 | 349C | 072F | 307C | 170F | 201D | 201D |
| 2023-09-14 | I13490 | 497C | 349C | 303F | 101A |  | 303F |

I searched all over StackOverflow to try and solve this problem but to no avail.  I assume doing if then else is an option starting with column "val5" and going down to column "val1" but I want to learn a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: sure, I'll add the code to make the tables

Comment: something like `df.apply(lambda row: row[row.isin(code_list)].values[-1] if row.isin(code_list).any() else None, axis=1)` works

Comment: code for dataframe table has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use apply for each row with a function that returns the first value that exists in the code_list starting with the right-most columns:

```
# returns the first match
def lambda_func(row, code_list):
  for x in row:
    if x in code_list:
      return x  
  return None

# define your list of "val" columns
val_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('val')][::-1]

df['val_final'] = df.apply(lambda row: lambda_func(row[val_cols], code_list), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         date      id  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5 val_final
0  2023-08-29   B3241  496C                              None
1  2023-09-08   A3290  349C  078F  274F                  349C
2  2023-09-12   D2903  349C  072F  307C  170F  201D      201D
3  2023-09-14  I13490  497C  0349  303F  101A            303F
```